# What browser is used on old Samsung Galaxy?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, samsung-galaxy-s-2, samsung-galaxy-s-4, browser, samsung-galaxy-s-5

What browser is used on the Samsung Galaxy S5, Galaxy S4, Galaxy S3 and Galaxy S2? I am testing my website on those models using [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/screenshots) but am experiencing problems. I think one of the HTC models is using the same browser because I am experiencing the same problems on it too.

Here are my test results:

https://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/b54b853ab379aae6088e14cae4de4a09ae45fc93

OTOH, Google Nexus appear to work for the most part.

Answer (score 1):

It's called "Samsung Internet for Android":

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sec.android.app.sbrowser&hl=en